# How to define a type and make sure it's part of another type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typing

I have a big type:

```
type BigType = {
  aaa: string,
  bbb?: number,
  ccc: boolean[],
  extra?: {
    [key in string]?: string
  },
  nested1: {
    nested2: {
      nested3: {
        [key in string]?: string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to define another type and make sure it's subset of the `BigType`, so I defined a `RecursivePartial` type:

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?:
  T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :
    T[P] extends object ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> :
      T[P];
};
```

and

```
type PartOf<T, X extends RecursivePartial<T>> = X;
```

Now I can define a small type which is only part of the BigType:

```
type SmallType = PartOf<BigType, {
  aaa: string;
  extra: { ddd: string };
  nested1: { nested2: {} }
}>
```

The problem is I can add properties which is not part of `BigType` too:

```
type SmallType = PartOf<BigType, {
  aaa: string;
  extra: { ddd: string };
  nested1: { nested2: {} },

  someOtherProperty1: string, // not part of BigType
  someOtherProperty2: string, // not part of BigType
}>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that object types in TypeScript are open and not [exact (see #12936 for discussion about exact types)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  That is, you can object types `A` and `B` where `A extends B` and `A` has properties that `B` doesn't mention.  This is actually a crucial part of interface/class hierarchies; without it, you couldn't add properties to subinterfaces/subclasses.  Still, there are times when it surprises people (especially because when you use object literal values the compiler performs additional [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) which makes it look like object types are exact).

Exact object types can't currently be represented in TypeScript as specific concrete types.  Instead, you have to use generics (see [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-368244671) for more information)

---

Anyway in your case I'd probably proceed by defining a `DeepPartial` and a `DeepNoExcess` type alias and using both of them in `TypeOf`.  `DeepPartial` looks like this:

```
type DeepPartial<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[K]> };
```

This is essentially the same as your `RecursivePartial`, I think.  As of TS3.1, [mapped types automatically map over arrays and tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) without needing special casing, and recursive mapped types that encounter primitive types leave them unmapped (see [microsoft/TypeScript#12447](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12447)).  That means you don't need to do much to get a recursive `Partial`.

`DeepNoExcess` has to take both the main type and the candidate type (since it's not possible to represent exact types concretely):

```
type DeepNoExcess<T, U> = { [K in keyof U]:
    K extends keyof T ? DeepNoExcess<Required<T>[K], U[K]> :
    never };
```

This walks down through the properties of the candidate type `U` and makes the property type `never` if the property key doesn't also exist in `T`.  I had to walk down into `Required<T>` instead of just `T` because your optional properties weren't being handled properly (`keyof (SomeType | undefined)` tends to be `never`).

Then `PartOf` is defined like this:

```
type PartOf<T, U extends DeepPartial<T> & DeepNoExcess<T, U>> = U;
```

This yields the behavior you are hoping for with your two examples:

```
type GoodSmallType = PartOf<BigType, {
    aaa: string;
    extra: { ddd: string };
    nested1: { nested2: {} }
}>; // okay

type BadSmallType = PartOf<BigType, {
    aaa: string;
    extra: { ddd: string };
    nested1: { nested2: {} },

    someOtherProperty1: string, // not part of BigType
    someOtherProperty2: string, // not part of BigType
}>; // error! Types of property 'someOtherProperty1' are incompatible.
```

Whether it meets all your use cases is not clear; there are lots of decisions you could make (like `Required<T>` instead of `T`) that will have implications for what types are accepted and what types are not.  But hopefully this gives you a way forward at least. Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgAoEMBOwCWyA2AeAKgHxQC8UA3lANoDSUGAdlANYQgD2AZlPgLoD8ALljwkaTDgK1exAL4BuALAAoUJBEIAcuwCiADwDGEAM7GCAGigBVYmUq16TVh25XeglVC9Q6EPcAgGABNjFjYuHih+DTBtfSNTXAAlCABHAFcMVAgggkJpSytpYg9lbygGCAA3CFQoWRUVNWgUdAB5TgtrKD8A4NC4BFaJPCIoADIYuMMTM3xCwltrJWUm8GgAIQwAc3x10gpPb2QT4WNgVEZt8yOvACMHoQr0gFs72puy7wMf4Tv2djYCDIBhUXifcq9VDIJ7kW7lajORxQc6XBjbARnC5XeGyCHeSrnHIARmEcK+CIqJgCQQATGT4ZSvISaQBmBkUpmUqhIxgo7HozH8tHbRlMhqc8oSqUqCVrdQAcQBQQAyi8cNg9uoyMMOrgtrt1pZyeUTsgsSKVpD-NCyVAgg6LVd6laCdSSXaWTl6RRZPVZYR5FAAPTBqDsZjIECNVT7DbIVXq7Ca-Y68R6g1aiDG+Fmp3o11eKHmij2x3C50KeFeoKk0s1n3kP14mPlYzsF4QNrAAAWtUQqHYkHQIDrqKullDFXYwCgYHE4e4mfW8Pbne7fdQA6HtVAPvH6MnYYYM7nC4iy8gAaDU9qg9QAEIeOtQhEwIPh6AoAByNdd3v9h+u6jt+UBoNAjAGB286YHcQIAHRAA)